# Weblogic 11g: how to change path to my trust.jks file for all Servers

Tags: ssl, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

i have put in /u01/app/oracle/product/fmw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/
2 files:
-trust.jks
-identity.jks
Then i have changed on Webblogic console, for Admin and managed servers,
the PATH to:
-Custom Identity Keystore
-Custom Trust Keystore

All looks good.
After weblogic restarts all servers are running, but
when i run this command on terminal `ps -eaf|grep weblogic`
i see this line:

```
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/DemoTrust.jks
```

As a result no one of my online interfaces are connecting.
I get the following error:

```
BEA-382513<con:reason>OSB Replace action failed updating variable "body": {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items</con:reason>
```

Can someone help me to correct the path for my Servers so that it would look for trust.jks and not the DemoTrust.jks?

Comment: have you tried changing the vm parameter from within your code or overriding it somehow?

Comment: I have configured the Path to my Trust and identity key in Admin server configuration. Maybe i need to change the default path to a keystore in MBean security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is by setting the flag on "SSL Listen Port Enabled"
thet can be found 
`Home >Summary of Environment >Summary of Servers >AdminServer -> Configuration/General.`
After this we need to go to this view:
Home>Summary of Environment >Summary of Servers >AdminServer >Summary of Servers->Control

Select AdminServer and Click on Restart SSL.
To see if changes bin done we need to execute the command:

```
ps -eaf|grep weblogic
```

and look for

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/**trust.jks**
```

If the end has the trust key file,in my case i called it trust.jks, then the change was performed successfully.